# QMediaPlayer to back in MainWindow QT

Tags: qt, c++17, qt-creator, qt6

I'm using this qt class to play .mp4 files as a brackground but it doesn't allow me to add buttons or anything else above.

[image]

well, it was already placed for QMediaPlayer to inherit 'centralwidget and widget' but without success, below is the code

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
ui->setupUi(this);
videoWidget = new QVideoWidget(ui->centralwidget);
player      = new QMediaPlayer;

player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/felli/Desktop/teste/videoplayback (2).mp4"));
player->setLoops(QMediaPlayer::Infinite);
player->play();

videoWidget->resize(1280, 720);
videoWidget->show();

pb = new QProgressBar(videoWidget);
pb->setGeometry(QRect(370, 370, 118, 23));
pb->setValue(30);
pb->show();
```

Comment: I do not see buttons in the code you shared.

Comment: look at the progress bar

Comment: We need to see the button code shared. You only shared parts of your main window without the button.

Comment: @LászlóPapp edited code

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you parent the progress bar to the video widget so that it gets tied to that rather than shown on top as you seem to would like it.

This code works fine for me:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProgressBar>

#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QVideoWidget>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget();
  QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
  
  player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
  player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/felli/Desktop/teste/videoplayback (2).mp4"));
  player->setLoops(QMediaPlayer::Infinite);
  player->play();
  
  videoWidget->resize(1280, 720);
  videoWidget->show();
  
  // Not parent it to the video widget to show it on top
  QProgressBar *pb = new QProgressBar();
  pb->setGeometry(QRect(370, 370, 118, 23));
  pb->setValue(30);
  pb->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: this way the video media is separated